# GitHub action, trigger from a certain condition

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I have a Repo, where people can upload their scripts, in which they solve a particular problem using more than one language.

The Scripts are segregated according to Languages. i.e. there is folders `Python`, `JavaScript`, `Go` etc and there are multiple subdirectories in them and they contain the script and a `README.md`.

I want to make a PyLint Action, so ta when someone starts a PR, the action tells me their PyLint score and I can decide whether to merge or not.

I want this action to be triggered only when someone Starts a PR and the commits have a `.py` file (i.e. Language used Is python).

Can someone guide me, please?

in `.yml` file I have

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    path:
      - '**.py'
```

This is not solving the issue.

Complete Workflow

```
name: PyLint Runner

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    path:
      - '**.py'

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v1
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install Requirements
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pylint
    - name: Run Pylint
      run: |
        python pyLint.py --path ./src --threshold 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set not the `path` but [`paths`](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpaths) key (plural):

```
name: PyLint Runner

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - '**.py'
```

That should trigger your workflow if the commit contains any modified `*.py` files. The documentation says the workflow will be triggered only for the modified files (the files already under version control). It says nothing about newly created files.

Comment: I see thanks for that info. So what you are saying is that as far as you know, only the files under VDS can be used (lack of appropriate word in my mind) in GitHub action?